# javascript format price

Tags: javascript, format

I wish to format a variable to a price format where if it is for example $90 then leave out the decimal which it already does anyway. But if the value is $44.5 then I want to format it as $44.50. I can do it in php not javascript.

PHP example:

```
number_format($price, !($price == (int)$price) * 2);
```

The code I want to format:

```
$(showdiv+' .calc_price span').html(sum_price);
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var price = 44.5;    
var dplaces = price == parseInt(price, 10) ? 0 : 2;
price = '$' + price.toFixed(dplaces);
```

Answer (score 1):

PHPJS has that code for you: http://phpjs.org/functions/money_format:876

Also provided by @Daok [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function priceFormatter(price)
{
    //Checks if price is an integer
    if(price == parseInt(price))
    {    
        return "$" + price;
    }

    //Checks if price has only 1 decimal
    else if(Math.round(price*10)/10 == price)
    {
        return "$" + price + "0";
    }

    //Covers other cases
    else
    {
        return "$" + Math.round(price*100)/100;
    }
}
```